# Ubuntu 16.10 Doesn't Recognize Cooling Fan

Tags: 16.10, fan, temperature

I recently bought a cooling fan for my laptop (HP Probook 4320t) and installed it along with a new heat sink. I went into the bios screen to verify the installation of the fan and it works just fine. But when I went into Ubuntu, the fan won't start. I installed lm-sensors and ran sensors to get an output. It appears as if Ubuntu isn't even seeing that the fan is there. If anyone would be able to help me here, I'd greatly appreciate it. The computer is very similar to the Probook 4320s, if that helps anyone.